# How to duplicate of a const slice of structs in D?

Tags: d

Let's assume I have a struct, that contains a slice:

```
struct Test{
    int[] arr; 
}
```

The problem is, that I'm unable to duplicate a const version of the Test struct:

```
void function(in Test tmp){
    ....
    Test copy = tmp.dup;//Compilation failure
    ....
}
```

I understand that the compile time error comes from the fact that `copy` and `tmp` would share the same `arr` slice, that would brake `tmp` constness. How to avoid this problem, without taking a non const Test object?

Comment: Dup isn't part of the struct API just of arrays. make an explicit copy using the copy constructor instead.

Comment: the error message is abysmal though, wow, struct.dup made me think my compiler had just vomited. but maybe it should work on them too, it certainly could

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest fix is to explicitly make a copy of Test with a copy of tmp:

```
Test copy = Test(tmp.arr.dup); // works
```

Here's a more generic duplicate function and example program:

```
struct Test{
    int[] arr; 
}

void f(in Test tmp) {
    Test copy = tmp.duplicate;
    import std.stdio;
    writeln(copy);
    copy.arr[0] = 10;
    writeln(copy);
    writeln(tmp);
}

import std.traits;

T duplicate(T)(in T t) if(is(T == struct)) {
    T copy;
    foreach(memberName; __traits(allMembers, T)) {
        static if(!hasIndirections!(typeof(__traits(getMember, t, memberName))))
            __traits(getMember, copy, memberName) = __traits(getMember, t, memberName);
        else
            __traits(getMember, copy, memberName) = __traits(getMember, t, memberName).dup;
    }
    return copy;
}

void main() {
    auto t = Test([20, 30]);
    f(t);
}
```

It loops over all members of the input struct and if it is a value type, just assigns it to a copy, and if not, tries to call .dup on it to make a copy. Works with array members. With some expansion, you could make it work with child structs and maybe pointers too.

Comment: This has a nasty part of always having to explicitly writing out parameters, Is there a simpler way?

Comment: write a function to do it for you like `Test dup() const {   return Test(arr.dup); } ` then you can tmp.dup yourself

Comment: @UldisK I edited it to add an example generic function, though I think a hand written dup member function like in my comment is generally clearer and not really hard to write.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid structs sharing data after being copied then define the [postblit constructor](http://dlang.org/struct.html#struct-postblit):

```
struct Test{
    int[] arr; 

    this(this){
        arr = arr.dup;
    }

}
```

This way every time Test is assigned to another variable the underlying array will be copied.

Comment: This is a good thing to know in general, but it doesn't work to make a mutable copy of a const struct (though maybe in theory it could, the compiler seems to be conservative about that array; I don't think it realizes it is safely copied). `test.d(11): Error: conversion error from const(Test) to Test`

Comment: then it needs a explicit opAssign that takes a `in Test` then